# Casting combobox objects back to their correct type

Tags: java, swing, combobox, casting

I have a combobox of objects (two types; ProductGroup and Family).  I would like to use a command to find out what type of object the selected item is.

I went out on a limb and tried

```
if (cbFamily.getSelectedItem() instanceof ProductGroup) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainWindow, "You have selected a ProductGroup")
}
```

I had no luck

Note: I am new to Java so I may need to ask for further clarification on some answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should works fine. Problem will be somewhere else. Use debugger, or write
"System.out.println(cbFamily.getSelectedItem().getClass());" before your "if" to determine what class is returned from your combobox.

Comment: You are correct, the Class is ListData, a Custom Class, the problem is because I have an edited custom ComboBoxModel that someone else wrote and it converts the objects to ListData prior to adding the data to the ComboBox. I will have to see if I can avoid this. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Great, I got it working.  I needed the ListData class in order to perform some of the formatting needed so I took the selectedItem and cast it back to ListData and then performed the instanceof and it is working.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What about implementing a toString() function which returns the class name? Or making use of [Object.getName()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29). You can also try overriding it and make your own.